# Starting Synergy client dims the screen

Tags: linux, fedora, synergy

I'm using Synergy to allow me to control my laptop while using my desktop's keyboard and mouse. Whenever I start the synergy client on the laptop, its screen dims, and also does so every time I move the mouse pointer from the desktop's screen over to the laptop's.

Both machines run Linux (Fedora 17, running KDE 4.9), both Synergys are version 1.3.7 (synergy-1.3.7-5.fc17.x86_64). The laptop has the charger plugged in, so it's not a power-saving feature.

Is this something that's under Synergy's control, or is it some external side-effect? If it's a feature, can I disable it? I definitely want to get rid of it.

Comment: Mhmmm ... the problem went away after a yum update of all packages (sans kernel). This did not change the synergy version, so I suspect it was an X/KDE issue. If anyone knows more, I'd still appreciate a pointer to the actual cause.